# How to create and upload a file in google Drive using Salesforce APEX and Drive APIs?

Tags: salesforce, google-drive-api, apex-code

I want to create and upload a document (txt) to google Drive with the help of Salesforce.com APEX code and Google Drive APIs.
    Do anybody has idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Since Google Drive SDK is basically HTTP request and there is [HttpRequest Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) in Apex, you can use Google Drive SDK with Apex. However, there is no official support for Apex in Google Drive, and you should build your own library for it. Here is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) about Drive API having some detail of requests and responses you will have with Drive SDK.

Comment: Thanks JunYoung for your help. Will see If I can do with REST APIs